# How to interpolate a columnof n number of pixels to m number of pixels in opencv c++?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, interpolation

I am working to extract a region from an image by drawing the circle and place the complete circular region linearly into another image.
First i draw a circle with known center and required radius 60. With help of `lineIterator` i extracted points along the line from centre to one endpoint on circle and placed all these points linearly into another image, done this for 360 lines as circle has 360 degrees.[image: shown in images below]
[image]

there is no problem at 0,90,180 and 270 degrees. but with angles in between the number of pixels get reduced and the blue line in my second image looks like mountains.
I want to interpolate each column from my second image so that the blue curves looks line a straight line.

I want to know how to interpolate a column of 44 pixels to 60 pixels? I hope by doing this i will get reauired image.

Any other suggestions from your side are also accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand but it seems that you don't use euclidean distance to extract point. I think with euclidean distance it will be better but as image is in discrete world you will have some noise...

Comment: Is this a good option for interpolation   ```resize(original, new, new.size(), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR);```

Comment: have you try [linearpolar or logpolar](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html)? with M=136 and center(630,360)

Comment: Unless you want inter-column interpolation, go for resize.